# Put image in .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

How to put image  in .jar using  Eclipse and how to load image from that .jar ?

Comment: Are you using ant to create the jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Put the image file into your source hierarchy and eclipse will include it in your jar. Call Class.getResourceAsStream to access it from classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In example below image file is placed to package com/vocrecaptor/swing/resource and set as icon to system tray icon.

```
SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
URL imgURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/vocrecaptor/swing/resource/tray.gif");
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imgURL);
trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, hint, menu);
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
tray.add(trayIcon);
```

In Eclipse a jar file can be created from menu File->Export->Java->Runnable JAR file. There you will need to choose executable class. Ant script is also can be generated for you.